# Auto Increment feature of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have created a table named as ABC. It has three columns which are as follows:-

[image]

The column `number_pk` `(int)` is the **primary key** of my table in which I have made the `auto increment` feature on for that column.

Now I have deleted two rows from that table say `Number_pk= 5` and `Number_pk =6`.

The table which I get now is like this:-

[image]

Now if I again enter two new rows in this table with the same value I get the two new `Number_pk starting from 7 and 8` i.e,

[image]

My question is that what is the logic behind this since I have deleted the two rows from the table. I know that a simple answer is because I have set the auto increment on for the primary key of my table. But I want to know is there any way that I can insert the two new entries starting from the last Number_pk without changing the design of my table?

And how the ***SQL Server manage this record since I have deleted the rows from the database??***

Comment: Why would you want that? Sometimes a requirement is not really a requirement

Comment: I was just checking it. And trying to find a solution as there could be situation where the int is full for the primary key then I know wee can use BigInt. So just thought that why cant we utitlize the unused one? I am not sure that is it feasible but just my query :)

Comment: Yeah, contiguous pk's are nice, but surely not necessary.

Comment: Yes I understand that I just wanted to know how SQL Server is actually managing it(if possible)!!

Comment: If you absolutely want a solution you could store the deleted ids in a separate table and when you assign id numbers in your code you can assign from the deleted ids table first before using autoincrement if the deleted ids table is empty.

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle:- Thanx for your reply but I already mentioned in my question that I dont want to change the design of my table!!! Its just what I was trying to achieve if possible!!

Comment: This wouldn't change the design of your table, it would change the design of your database and the logic of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should not do this until their is a specific requirement.

1.) Get the max id:

```
Declare @id int
Select @id = Max(Number_pk) From ABC
SET @id = @id + 1;
```

2.) And reset the Identity Column:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('ABC', RESEED, @id)
```

[DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This won't work if you delete rows in the middle. For example if you have rows 1,2,3,4 and you delete 3 the max is still 4.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is guaranteeing that the generated numbers are unique. An ID field does not neccessarily have to have a meaning, but rather is most often used to identify a unique record, thus making it easier to perform operations on it.

If your database is designed properly, the deleted ID numbers would not have been possible to delete if they were referenced by any other tables in a foreign key relationship, thus preventing records from being orphaned in that way.

If you absolutely want to have entries sequences, you could consider issuing a `RESEED`, but as suggested, it would not really give you much advantages.

The identity record is "managed" because SQL Server will keep track of which numbers have been issued, regardless of whether they are still present or not.

Should you ever want to delete all records from a table, there are two ways to do so (provided no foreign key relatsons exist):

```
DELETE FROM Table
```

`DELETE` just removes the records, but the next INSERTED value will continue where the ID numbering left of.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE
```

`TRUNCATE` will actually RESEED the table, thus guaranteeing it starts again at the value you originally specified (most likely 1).